# Powershell: resolve path that might not exist?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to process a list of files that may or may not be up to date and may or may not yet exist.  In doing so, I need to resolve the full path of an item, even though the item may be specified with relative paths.  However, `Resolve-Path` prints an error when used with a non-existant file.

For example, **What's the simplest, cleanest way to resolve `".\newdir\newfile.txt"` to `"C:\Current\Working\Directory\newdir\newfile.txt"` in Powershell**?

Note that `System.IO.Path`'s static method use with the *process's* working directory - which isn't the powershell current location.

Comment: In PowerShell 2 and 3 you can use `Resolve-Path`

Comment: That fails for non-existant paths, and I'm trying to create files, so that's an expected scenario.

Comment: This should be really a feature of Resolve-Path out of the box. It actually does resolve it, but then throws an unwanted error...

Comment: Yes, it should, someone needs to propose that.

Comment: Related: Here's a method that allows you to resolve an absolute or relative path, using the working directory by default or a given base path when provided.  In PSCore this doesn't have a side effect of changing your working directory / in PS Desktop it has a finally block to revert you to your original directory: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77149822/361842

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You want:

```
c:\path\exists\> $ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath(".\nonexist\foo.txt")
```

returns:

```
c:\path\exists\nonexists\foo.txt
```

This has the advantage of working with PSPaths, not native filesystem paths. A PSPath may not map 1-1 to a filesystem path, for example if you mount a psdrive with a multi-letter drive name.

What's a pspath?

```
ps c:\> new-psdrive temp filesystem c:\temp
...
ps c:\> cd temp:
ps temp:\>
```

temp:\ is a drive-qualified pspath that maps to a win32 (native) path of c:\temp.

-Oisin

Comment: Nice. I guess I saw some similar function when looking through Reflector to ResolvePathCommand. Going through code is good for inspiration ;)

Comment: Many thanks!  That command may be a little longwinded, but it's *exactly* what I was looking for.

Comment: OMG, how is it that the `Resolve-Path` cmdlet doesn't have a flag to not test that path as well.

Comment: @JohnLeidegren Probably because Resolve-Path resolves paths, and we're looking for an unresolved path.

Comment: @x0n According to the [Approved Verbs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714428(v=vs.85).aspx) page, all Resolve means is, "Maps a shorthand representation of a resource to a more complete representation." It says nothing about checking for the resource's existence.

Comment: ps>[io.path]::GetFullPath("./somedir")   returns "D:\bla-bla-folder\somedir"

Comment: @Vladislav It's not that simple - that only works for win32 paths, not powershell paths (they are different things) http://www.nivot.org/post/2010/03/05/PowerShellThePatchworkOfPathsPSPathsAndProviderPaths

Comment: @x0n, what do mean in "powershell paths"? "..win32" - i tested on my 64bit windows 7

Comment: @Vladislav powershell drives are not the same as windows drives. The have the same name(s) by default, but they don't have to. Read my blog post: http://www.nivot.org/post/2010/03/05/PowerShellThePatchworkOfPathsPSPathsAndProviderPaths

Comment: Finally, I have a proper implementation that works with relative normalized paths and absolute on paths that don't exist and on drives that don't exist, and on any powershell provider. https://gist.github.com/Luiz-Monad/d5aea290087a89c070da6eec84b33742#test-proper_drive_provider_path_from_pspath

Answer (score 49):

When `Resolve-Path` fails due to the file not existing, the fully resolved path is accessible from the thrown error object.

You can use a function like the following to fix `Resolve-Path` and make it work like you expect.

```
function Force-Resolve-Path {
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Calls Resolve-Path but works for files that don't exist.
    .REMARKS
        From http://devhawk.net/blog/2010/1/22/fixing-powershells-busted-resolve-path-cmdlet
    #>
    param (
        [string] $FileName
    )

    $FileName = Resolve-Path $FileName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue `
                                       -ErrorVariable _frperror
    if (-not($FileName)) {
        $FileName = $_frperror[0].TargetObject
    }

    return $FileName
}
```

Comment: IMHO, the best answer so far

Comment: Why do you need "$FileName = $_frperror[0].TargetObject"? Why not just silently continue?

Comment: @Rookian Because `ResolvePath` returns `$null` if the path does not exist.

Answer (score 25):

I think you're on the right path.  Just use [Environment]::CurrentDirectory to set .NET's notion of the process's current dir e.g.:

```
[Environment]::CurrentDirectory = $pwd
[IO.Path]::GetFullPath(".\xyz")
```

Comment: Right, but that has side-effects and a bit of nasty interop I'd like to avoid - I'd kind of hoped that this 'd be something powershell (which is a shell scripting language, after all) could handle natively...  Anyhow, +1 for an actual option!

Comment: It also has the problem whereby the $pwd may not actually be a real path on the filesystem either; for example if you mount a psdrive with a multi-letter drive name.

Comment: Good point.  Of course, you can grab the .NET current dir first, then set it to a filesystem provider path (not use $pwd) and then reset current dir back to its original value.

Comment: If you are going to change the process CWD, you might as well use the internal infrastructure of the powershell, it has a nice stack of paths that doesn't change the process CWD.    https://gist.github.com/Luiz-Monad/d5aea290087a89c070da6eec84b33742#test-normalize_relative_path

Answer (score 11):

```
Join-Path (Resolve-Path .) newdir\newfile.txt
```

Comment: You can also find more examples in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: Only works if assuming 'newdir' is relative. `Join-Path (Resolve-Path .) F:\thisuer\specified\absolutepath\inparameter`

Answer (score 7):

This has the advantage of not having to set the CLR Environment's current directory:

```
[IO.Path]::Combine($pwd,"non\existing\path")
```

#### NOTE

This is not functionally equivalent to [x0n's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3040982/64334). `System.IO.Path.Combine` only combines string path segments. Its main utility is keeping the developer from having to worry about slashes. `GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath` will traverse the input path relative to the present working directory, according to the `.`'s and `..`'s.

Comment: Nice n short!  Is this exactly equivalent to the `GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath`-based solution, or are there subtle differences?

Comment: Not really a viable solution. It assumes the psdrive has the same name as the provider backing store's. You can have a drive in powershell called "stuff:\" that is mapped to "c:\" for example, this solution would pass the psdrive name instead of the win32 name which would fail

Comment: @x0n thanks for bringing up that interesting caveat.

Comment: There are very subtle differences https://gist.github.com/Luiz-Monad/d5aea290087a89c070da6eec84b33742#test-combine_pwd_then_getfullpath 
and not so subtle https://gist.github.com/Luiz-Monad/d5aea290087a89c070da6eec84b33742#test-only_unresolved_provider_path_from_pspath

Answer (score 2):

I've found that the following works well enough.

```
$workingDirectory = Convert-Path (Resolve-Path -path ".")
$newFile = "newDir\newFile.txt"
Do-Something-With "$workingDirectory\$newFile"
```

Convert-Path can be used to get the path as a string, although this is not always the case. See [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156816.aspx) entry on COnvert-Path for more details.

Comment: `Convert-Path` was the solution to get a path with `Temp:` Drive to get the actual filesystem path.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Get-FullName()
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $True)] [object[]] $Path
    )
    Begin{
        $Path = @($Path);
    }
    Process{
        foreach($p in $Path)
        {
            if($p -eq $null -or $p -match '^\s*$'){$p = [IO.Path]::GetFullPath(".");}
            elseif($p -is [System.IO.FileInfo]){$p = $p.FullName;}
            else{$p = [IO.Path]::GetFullPath($p);}
            $p;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This only works if using the psdrive names are the same as the backing drive name. Also only works for win32 file paths and will fail on every other provider.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this code in my case. I needed to create a file later in the the script, so this code presumes you have write access to the target folder.

```
$File = ".\newdir\newfile.txt"
If (Test-Path $File) {
    $Resolved = (Resolve-Path $File).Path
} else {
    New-Item $File -ItemType File | Out-Null
    $Resolved = (Resolve-Path $File).Path
    Remove-Item $File
}
```

I also enclosed `New-Item` in `try..catch` block, but that goes out of this question.

Comment: This is bad, it modifies the Filesystem and doesn't work with providers like the registry. Look here for a proper implementation that I'm going to submit to be a parameter for "Resolve-Path" https://gist.github.com/Luiz-Monad/d5aea290087a89c070da6eec84b33742#test-proper_drive_provider_path_from_pspath

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I needed to find the folder 3 levels up from a folder that does not exist yet to determine the name for a new folder I wanted to create... It's complicated. Anyway, this is what I ended up doing:

```
($path -split "\\" | select -SkipLast 3) -join "\\"
```

Comment: That's not relevant, but its simple actually. just do `Split-Path -Parent (Split-Path -Parent (Split-Path -Parent 'a/b/c/d'))`

Answer (score 0):

```
function Get-ResolvedPath($path)
{
    [System.Uri]$uri = New-Object System.Uri($path);
    return $uri.LocalPath;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

There is an accepted answer here, but it is quite lengthy and there is a simpler alternative available.

In any recent version of Powershell, you can use `Test-Path -IsValid -Path 'C:\Probably Fake\Path.txt'`

This simply verifies that there are no illegal characters in the path and that the path could be used to store a file. If the target doesn't exist, `Test-Path` won't care in this instance -- it's only being asked to test if the provided path is potentially valid.

Comment: This *tests* a path for validity; I want to resolve it into an absolute path (e.g. for normalization purposes, or to be able to store the path and reuse it in another context with a different environment).

Answer (score -2):

Both most popular answers don't work correctly on paths on not existing drives.

```
function NormalizePath($filename)
{
    $filename += '\'
    $filename = $filename -replace '\\(\.?\\)+','\'
    while ($filename -match '\\([^\\.]|\.[^\\.]|\.\.[^\\])[^\\]*\\\.\.\\') {
        $filename = $filename -replace '\\([^\\.]|\.[^\\.]|\.\.[^\\])[^\\]*\\\.\.\\','\'
    }
    return $filename.TrimEnd('\')
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained what this is doing.  This is not something that's going to be obvious what's going on at first glance, worse so for someone not well-versed in regex.  Also, when I pass the sample path in the question to this function, it just returns the same path.  Passing `'C:\'` returns `'C:'`, which means something different.  I get the correct result for `'C:\Dir1\..\File1'`, but `'Dir1\..\File1'` is returned unmodified and `'Dir1\Dir2\..\File1'` just becomes `'Dir1\File1'`, not an absolute path.  Is this intended to be used before one of those answers' solutions?

Comment: Also: manipulating structured strings via regex is notoriously tricky.  A solution like this might easily have nasty corner cases; and a it looks like @BACON already found a few.  Even if you can *do* it correctly, it's going to be almost impossible to *verify* it's correct; a huge test set would be a good start.

Answer (score -3):

You can just set the -errorAction to "SilentlyContinue" and use Resolve-Path

```
5 >  (Resolve-Path .\AllFilerData.xml -ea 0).Path
C:\Users\Andy.Schneider\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Scripts\AllFilerData.xml

6 >  (Resolve-Path .\DoesNotExist -ea 0).Path

7 >
```

Comment: Setting the error action to 0 doesn't actually fix the problem that resolve path won't then resolve that (perfectly valid) path.

Comment: you do not get any path if the path does not exist

Answer (score -5):

Check if the file exists before resolving:

```
if(Test-Path .\newdir\newfile.txt) { (Resolve-Path .\newdir\newfile.txt).Path }
```

Comment: I need to resolve both existing and non-existing files; I'll be creating the non-existant ones.

Comment: this solution still does not return the path for a non-existing file