# Is there an powershell cmdlet equivalent of [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath($fileName); when $fileName doesn't exist?

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

If $fileName exists then the cmdlet equivalent of [`[System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath($fileName);`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx) is [`(Get-Item $fileName).FullName`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347553.aspx). However, an exception is thrown if the path does not exist. Is their another cmdlet I am missing?

[`Join-Path`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347593.aspx) is not acceptable because it will not work when an absolute path is passed:

```
C:\Users\zippy\Documents\deleteme> join-path $pwd 'c:\config.sys'
C:\Users\zippy\Documents\deleteme\c:\config.sys
C:\Users\zippy\Documents\deleteme>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Join-Path` would be the way to get a path for a non-existant item I believe. Something like this:

```
join-path $pwd $filename
```

Update:

I don't understand why you don't want to use .Net "code". Powershell is .Net based. All cmdlets are .Net code. Only valid reason for avoiding it is that when you use .Net Code, the current directory is the directory from which Powershell was started and not `$pwd`

I am just listing the ways I believe this can be done so that you can handle absolute and relateive paths. None of them seem simpler than the `GetFullPath()` one:

```
$ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath($filename)
```

If you are worried if absolute path is passed or not, you can do something like:

```
if(Split-Path $filename -IsAbsolute){
    $filename
}
else{
    join-path $pwd $filename  # or join-path $pwd (Split-Path -Leaf $filename)
}
```

This is the ugly one

```
 $item = Get-Item $filename -ea silentlycontinue
 if (!$item) {
 $error[0].targetobject
 } else{
 $item.fullname
 }
```

Similar question, with similar answers: [Powershell: resolve path that might not exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3038337/526535)

Comment: Join-Path creates its own problem, it falls apart when the parameter passed is an absolute path. If a combination of this and other Cmdlets will fix the issue, thats more complex than including .net code.

Comment: @Justin Dearing - Updated my answer again.

Comment: I have nothing against calling the .NET methods. I just wanted to know if their was a cmdlet equivalent just like Test-Path is the equivalent to [System.IO.File]::Exists(). The [script](https://gist.github.com/1166670) that prompted this question actually makes two [PInvoke calls](http://pinvoke.net/), so I have nothing against calling .NET or unmanaged functions in PowerShell.

Comment: There is also [System.IO.Path]::Combine($pwd, $yourIncompletePath).

Comment: Split-Path d:folder -IsAbsolute gives $True, but the resolved path above depends on the current directory on drive d:
I would venture to suggest that this path is 'relative'. At the least it is not a complete path spec, therefore Split-Path -IsAbsolute does not work correctly for the purposes of excluding only absolute and full/complete paths from the above processing.

Comment: After further testing: The 'ugly' Get-item method appears to work in this <drive:> + <non-dot relative path> (e.g. x:myfolder as opposed to x:\myfolder) case, whereas, the Split-Path -IsAbsolute method does not.

Comment: GetFullPath() will resolve path, alternative would be `Join-Path $pwd "..\otherfolder" -Resolve`, but it would fail if the folder does not exist. Without -Resolve, Join-Path just concatenate two strings adding/removing "\" as necessary

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Test-Path cmdlet to check it exists before getting the fullname.

```
if (Test-Path $filename) {(Get-Item $fileName).FullName}
```

EDIT:

Just seen your comment above about Test-Path being the equivalent to the [system.io.file]::exists() function and I believe I understand your question better now.

No is the answer as I see it but you could make your own.

```
function Get-Fullname {
  param($filename)
  process{
      if (Test-Path $filename) {(Get-Item $fileName).FullName} 
  }
}
```

you could tidy it up some by making the parameters accept pipeline, both strings and properties but it serves the purpose.

Comment: If the `$fileName`does not contain the whole path, you may have to test against full path as well: `$filepath = (Get-Item $fileName).FullName; if (Test-Path $filepath) { #do something with $filepath }`

Comment: @tbergstedt it shouldn't as either $filename is a relative filename in which case Test-Path will work or it is an absolute again this will work. I don't see another outcome...

Answer (score -1):

You can remove the drive qualifier of 'c:\config.sys' (Using Split-Path) and then join the two paths:

```
PS > Join-Path $pwd (Split-Path 'c:\config.sys' -NoQualifier)    
C:\Users\zippy\Documents\deleteme\config.sys
```

Comment: -1 - That is not the OP wants. If you give `c:\config.sys` output should be that itself. If you give `.\config.sys` output should be `C:\Users\zippy\Documents\deleteme\config.sys`, if you give `..\notexisting.txt` output should be `C:\Users\zippy\Documents\notexisting.txt` and so on. And even for what you are showing `-Leaf` is a better option that `-NoQualifier`.