# How to remove Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\ from path

Tags: powershell

i am comparing to folders with all their subfolders with powershell and its working fine on my local machine. but when i tried it on server its give me error and append

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\
```

to all the files

if any one have do such work earlier please help

my script is

```
$Path = '\\Server1\Folder1'

Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse | ? { !$_.PSIsContainer } | % { 
        Add-Member -InputObject $_ -MemberType NoteProperty -Name RelativePath -Value $_.FullName.Substring($Path)
        $_
    }
```

and its give me error

```
Cannot convert argument "0", with value: "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\Server1\Folder1\ServerListPowershell", for "Substring" to type "System.Int32": "Cannot convert value "M
icrosoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\Server1\Folder1\ServerListPowershell" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format.""
At C:\Users\cwr.satish.kumar\AppData\Local\Temp\898f72f1-a0d3-4003-b268-128c5efc9f2b.ps1:14 char:108
+         Add-Member -InputObject $_ -MemberType NoteProperty -Name RelativePath -Value $_.FullName.Substring <<<< ($Path)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument
```

please help

Comment: What happened to all your underscores in $_ variables?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try the `Convert-Path` cmdlet:

```
PS> Convert-Path Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\windows\system32
C:\windows\system32
```

Comment: NB: This requires that the path exist on the machine on which it's executed (so if the path were returned from `Invoke-Command` on a remote machine, then `Convert-Path` were run against the results locally, you'd get an error).  To avoid such issues you can use: `$ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3040982/361842)

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure why the `FullName` property is prepending the powershell provider to the name, that's usually what you get when in the `PsPath` property.

At any rate, the reason why your attempt to strip it is failing is because your are passing a String to the [SubString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6.aspx) member function when it expects an integer index. To get the index of the start of your path, use the [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx) member function:

```
$justThePath = $_.FullName.SubString($_.FullName.IndexOf($Path))
```

Comment: Now script give me other error  Method invocation failed because [System.IO.FileInfo] doesn't contain a method named 'IndexOf'.
At \AppData\Local\Temp\78c0b727-7a26-4b1f-8250-43262dbb326e.ps1:14 char:110
+         Add-Member -InputObject $_ -MemberType NoteProperty -Name RelativePath -Value $_.SubString($_.IndexOf <<<< ($Path))#$_.FullName.Substring($Path)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (IndexOf:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Comment: @satishkumar oops, I forgot the `fullname` property. See my updated answer.

Comment: Again the same error `Directory: \\Server1\ServerListPowershell\PowerScript

Mode  LastWriteTime Length Name 
----  -------------     ------ ----  
-ar- 10/9/2012 12:03 PM 1473 01 Server.ps1
Exception calling "Substring" with "1" argument(s): "StartIndex cannot be less than zero. Parameter name: startIndex" At AppData\Local\Temp\78c0b727.ps1:16 char:108 + Add-Member -InputObject $_ -MemberType NoteProperty -Name RelativePath -Value  $_.FullName.SubString <<<< ($_.FullName.IndexOf($Path))
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedEr`

Comment: @satishkumar No, that's not the same error, you're getting "StartIndex cannot be less than zero" which means that IndexOf() can't find $Path in the string. You have something else going on. What is the value of $_ and $Path when it fails?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Substring()` as well. For example:

```
$path = "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\SERVERNAME\HOSTNAME\FOLDER"
$result = $path.Substring($path.IndexOf("FileSystem::") + 12)
Write-Output $result # Output: "\\SERVERNAME\HOSTNAME\FOLDER"
```