# Do Tfs Powershell tools work wtih remote workspaces?

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfs-power-tools

Good day.
I created a tfs-workspace on a remote computer, and worked with it in Visual Studio. All fine, check-ins and check-outs work correctly. 
Today I decided to automate some tasks, but Powershell tools throws various error during working with this workspace.

I checked scripts' work on local folder - all fine.
I've tried to use variations of UNC paths (FileSystem::myPath), Resolve-Path, Get-ChildItem, Get-TfsChildItem, but all of it doesn,t work. 
tf checkout even can't determine the workspace.

Are there any variants to work with a workspace on remote computer in PowerShell?

P.S. TFS, VS, TFPT of 13th version. 
P.P.S. I can't use "net use" or it's analogue.

P.P.P.S Commands and results:

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\srv-tfsmain\D$\NetWorkspace\MyUser\Test> tf checkout 15
tf : Unable to determine the workspace. You may be able to correct this by running 'tf workspaces /collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl'.


Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\srv-tfsmain\D$\NetWorkspace\MyUser\Test> Add-TfsPendingChange -edit 15
Add-TfsPendingChange : The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. $path


Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\srv-tfsmain\D$\NetWorkspace\MyUser\Test> Add-TfsPendingChange -edit (Resolve-Path 15)
Add-TfsPendingChange : Cannot bind parameter 'Item'. Cannot convert the "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\srv-tfsmain\D$\NetWorkspace\MyUser\Test\15" value of type "System.Management.Automation.PathInfo" to type "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.PowerShell.QualifiedItemSpec".
```

Upd 1. The error was in the incorrect path: Workspace was mapped to \srv-tfsmain\NetWorkspace\MyUser\Test, and i used command in \srv-tfsmain\D$\NetWorkspace\MyUser\Test. After correcting path, tf works fine, but

```
Add-TfsPendingChange -edit
```

doesn't work with any form of UNC path.

Comment: Please post your scripts with related errors.

Comment: imho, your path seems undefined to powershell, I tried to search for similar strings and found out this thread, can you try to use `convert-path` to determine the real path of the remote workspace path of yours, link [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14652333/how-to-remove-microsoft-powershell-core-filesystem-from-path)

Comment: @Beytan Kurt , I tried to use Convert-Path. It returns fileName in \\server\D$\path\fileName mode. Add-tfsPendingChange -edit doesn't work with such parameter too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It cannot work that way. The TFS concept of workspace implies that you give command the same path you defined in the workspace. So if on **PC01** you defined workspace **WRK01** that maps `$/MyProject` to `C:\wrk01`, you must run the command locally with `C:\wrk01`; `\\PC01\c$\work01` or else won't work.

Using Powershell, you can use a remote session to run the cmdlets locally (but they must be installed on the target machine), see `Enter-PSSession` to start.

Comment: but I can work with this workspace in Visual Studio. Does VS use Enter-PSSession-like mechanics?

Comment: @user3603450 No, it does not.  What do you mean you can work with it in Visual Studio?

Comment: @EdwardThomson, Because I work with it in Visual Studio right now. :)