# In PowerShell, how can I test if a user-supplied string represents a full absolute path?

Tags: powershell, path, relative-path, absolute-path

I have a script which allows the user to specify a location for a file which the script will write to. I want to check that the given string represents an **absolute**, rather than relative, file path. So this would pass:

```
C:\Folder\MyFile.txt
```

But these would fail:

```
.\Folder\MyFile.txt
..\MyFile.txt
MyFile.txt
```

Regardless of whether those files/folders exist already.

I'm not concerned with checking for e.g. invalid characters (which other questions I found while searching were concerned with). I could use a quick and dirty regular expression to check it starts with "^[a-zA-Z]:\" but I was wondering if the functionality already existed in PowerShell to do this.

If the script detects it's not an absolute path, the script will then convert it to a full path by inserting the full path of the current directory - so if there's a function which can do that directly then that will also be useful.

Comment: You can use commands like [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-RU/library/hh849858.aspx) or [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-RU/library/hh849856.aspx) to perform path conversions. I also strongly recommend you to use `Get-Help *<keyword>*` to get all available commands and then you can use `Get-Help <your command> -online` to get full command description with examples.

Comment: Resolve-Path and Convert-Path both require the specified file/folder to exist already, I want something which doesn't require that. I didn't know about the -online parameter though.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3040982/291709

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Have flagged as duplicate.