# How do I get the absolute path based on either relative or absolute paths in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, path

Consider the following situation: I have a parameter, or a config variable, that sets the output directory of a script. Obviously, this parameter should also be able to be absolute:

```
RepoBackup.ps1 -OutputDirectory .\out
RepoBackup.ps1 -OutputDirectory D:\backup
```

In the script, I use `(Get-Item -Path './').FullName` in combination with `Join-Path` to determine the absolute path of my output directory, because I might need to use `Set-Location` to change the current directory - which makes working with relative paths complicated.

But:

```
Join-Path C:\code\ .\out  # => C:\code\.\out  (which is exactly what i need)
Join-Path C:\code\ D:\    # => C:\code\D:\    (which is not only not what i need, but invalid)
```

I considered using `Resolve-Path` and do something like `Resolve-Path D:\backup`, but if the directory doesn't exist (yet), this yields an error about not being able to find the path.

So, how can I get the absolute path of my `$OutputDirectory`, accepting both absolute and relative input, as well as paths that don't yet exist?

Comment: Hint: `[IO.Path]::IsPathRooted()` tells if a path is rooted or relative.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038337/powershell-resolve-path-that-might-not-exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function did the job for me:

```
function Join-PathOrAbsolute ($Path, $ChildPath) {
    if (Split-Path $ChildPath -IsAbsolute) {
        Write-Verbose ("Not joining '$Path' with '$ChildPath'; " +
            "returning the child path as it is absolute.")
        $ChildPath
    } else {
        Write-Verbose ("Joining path '$Path' with '$ChildPath', " +
            "child path is not absolute")
        Join-Path $Path $ChildPath
    }
}

# short version, without verbose messages:

function Join-PathOrAbsolute ($Path, $ChildPath) {
  if (Split-Path $ChildPath -IsAbsolute) { $ChildPath }
  else { Join-Path $Path $ChildPath }
}
```

```
Join-PathOrAbsolute C:\code .\out  # => C:\code\.\out (just the Join-Path output)
Join-PathOrAbsolute C:\code\ D:\   # => D:\ (just the $ChildPath as it is absolute)
```

It just checks whether the latter path is absolute and returns it if it is, otherwise it just runs `Join-Path` on both `$Path` and `$ChildPath`.
Note that this doesn't consider the base `$Path` to be relative, but for my use case this is perfectly enough. (I use `(Get-Item -Path './').FullName` as the base path, which is absolute anyway.)

```
Join-PathOrAbsolute .\ D:\    # => D:\
Join-PathOrAbsolute .\ .\out  # => .\.\out
```

Note that while `.\.\` and `C:\code\.\out` does indeed look weird, it is valid and resolves to the correct path. It's just the output of PowerShell's integrated `Join-Path` function, after all.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the .Net [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=net-7.0) method, which does exactly what you want.

```
[IO.Path]::Combine('C:\code\', '.\out')  # => 'C:\code\.\out'
[IO.Path]::Combine('C:\code\', 'D:\')    # => 'D:\'
```