# Resolve a path which may not exist relative to a given base path

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-core

Is there a way in PowerShell (v5 or core) to resolve a path which may not exist relative to a given base path?  Note: I also want to ensure that if the given "relative path" is actually an absolute path, that it still resovles correctly.

I can already do this by changing the working directory; but I want a way to do the below without changing my working directory (as I don't like side effects).  Is there a native alternative to the below function?

```
Function Resolve-RelativePath {
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$Path
        ,
        [Parameter()]
        [string]$BasePath = '.'
    )
    Push-Location -Path $BasePath -ErrorAction Stop # the base path must exist; it's only the relative path which doesn't have to
    try {
        $ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath($Path)
    } finally {
        Pop-Location # try to avoid side effects
    }
}
```

Note: To confirm my expectations, running the below with the above function should return `true` for the "tests" below:

```
# ensure our base path exists for the below demos
New-Item -Path 'c:\temp\demo\ChildFolderThatExists'  -ItemType Directory -Force | Out-Null
New-Item -Path 'c:\temp\demo2\ChildFolderThatExists' -ItemType Directory -Force | Out-Null 
Set-Location -Path 'c:\temp\demo'

# the "tests"
(Resolve-RelativePath -Path 'ChildFolderThatExists'                                   ) -eq 'c:\temp\demo\ChildFolderThatExists'
(Resolve-RelativePath -Path 'ChildFolderThatDoesntExist'                              ) -eq 'c:\temp\demo\ChildFolderThatDoesntExist'
(Resolve-RelativePath -Path '../../someOtherFolder/Whatever'                          ) -eq 'c:\someOtherFolder\Whatever'
(Resolve-RelativePath -Path 'c:\absolute'                                             ) -eq 'c:\absolute'

(Resolve-RelativePath -Path 'ChildFolderThatExists' -BasePath 'c:\temp\demo2'         ) -eq 'c:\temp\demo2\ChildFolderThatExists'
(Resolve-RelativePath -Path 'ChildFolderThatDoesntExist' -BasePath 'c:\temp\demo2'    ) -eq 'c:\temp\demo2\ChildFolderThatDoesntExist'
(Resolve-RelativePath -Path '../../someOtherFolder/Whatever' -BasePath 'c:\temp\demo2') -eq 'c:\someOtherFolder\Whatever'
(Resolve-RelativePath -Path 'c:\absolute' -BasePath 'c:\temp\demo2'                   ) -eq 'c:\absolute'
```

Comment: As far as I can tell this a dupplicate with: [Powershell: resolve path that might not exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3038616/1701026)

Comment: @iRon it's slightly different to that... the linked question wants to get the path relative to the working directory, whilst I want to be able to specify the base path without amending the working directory.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution in [.net core](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfullpath?view=net-7.0)

```
$Path = 'c:\temp\demo'
$RelativePath = 'ChildFolderThatExists'
[System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath($Path, $RelativePath)
```

Note: the option to provide a base path does not exist in [.net framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfullpath?view=netframework-4.8.1), so this will only work in PWSH.

To ensure this works with both versions of powershell, and to avoid some differences in how `.` is resolved, here's an updated version of the above function, which has no side effects in PWSH, but still uses the `Push-Location` workaround in older PowerShell versions.

```
Function Resolve-RelativePath {
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$Path
        ,
        [Parameter()]
        [string]$BasePath = '.'
    )
    if (($PSVersionTable.PSEdition -eq 'Core') -or ([Environment]::Version.Major -ge 5)) { # environemt version is the better check, but doesn't exist in all versions: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/commit/fe5f4fbebc9e85c8e512a273567719dca15ac764
        $BasePath = [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath($BasePath, (Get-Location))
        [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath($Path, $BasePath)
    } else {
        Push-Location -Path $BasePath -ErrorAction Stop # the base path must exist; it's only the relative path which doesn't have to
        try {
            $ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath($Path)
        } finally {
            Pop-Location # try to avoid side effects
        }
    }
}


# ensure our base path exists for the below demos
New-Item -Path 'c:\temp\demo\ChildFolderThatExists'  -ItemType Directory -Force | Out-Null
New-Item -Path 'c:\temp\demo2\ChildFolderThatExists' -ItemType Directory -Force | Out-Null 
Set-Location -Path 'c:\temp\demo'

# the "tests"
(Resolve-RelativePath -Path 'ChildFolderThatExists'                                   ) -eq 'c:\temp\demo\ChildFolderThatExists'
(Resolve-RelativePath -Path 'ChildFolderThatDoesntExist'                              ) -eq 'c:\temp\demo\ChildFolderThatDoesntExist'
(Resolve-RelativePath -Path '../../someOtherFolder/Whatever'                          ) -eq 'c:\someOtherFolder\Whatever'
(Resolve-RelativePath -Path 'c:\absolute'                                             ) -eq 'c:\absolute'

(Resolve-RelativePath -Path 'ChildFolderThatExists' -BasePath 'c:\temp\demo2'         ) -eq 'c:\temp\demo2\ChildFolderThatExists'
(Resolve-RelativePath -Path 'ChildFolderThatDoesntExist' -BasePath 'c:\temp\demo2'    ) -eq 'c:\temp\demo2\ChildFolderThatDoesntExist'
(Resolve-RelativePath -Path '../../someOtherFolder/Whatever' -BasePath 'c:\temp\demo2') -eq 'c:\someOtherFolder\Whatever'
(Resolve-RelativePath -Path 'c:\absolute' -BasePath 'c:\temp\demo2'                   ) -eq 'c:\absolute'
```