# How can I convert a relative path to a fully qualified path in a DOS batch file?

Tags: batch-file, dos, relative-path

I am writing a batch file that does a number of operations in a folder that is specified relative to the first argument passed in to the batch file.  Within the batch file, I would like to echo to the user the the folder I am working in.  However, every time I echo the path, it contains the ....\ that I used to determine where to place my folder.  For example.

```
set TempDir=%1\..\Temp
echo %TempDir%
```

So, if I run my batch file with a parameter `\FolderA`, the output of the echo statement is `FolderA\..\Temp` instead of `\Temp` as I would expect.

Comment: See also ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645843/batch-file-resolve-absolute-path-from-relative-path-and-or-file-name

Comment: If you're using Powershell, this is a good solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495618/how-to-normalize-a-path-in-powershell

Comment: If you're not using Powershell, consider using Powershell to make the above solution available to you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SET "TempDir=%~1\..\Temp"
CALL :normalise "%TempDir%"
ECHO %TempDir%
…

:normalise
SET "TempDir=%~f1"
GOTO :EOF

…
```

The `:normalise` subroutine uses the `%~f1` expression to transform the relative path into the complete one and store it back to `TempDir`.

---

**UPDATE**

Alternatively, you could use a FOR loop, like this:

```
SET "TempDir=%~1\..\Temp"
FOR /F "delims=" %%F IN ("%TempDir%") DO SET "TempDir=%%~fF"
ECHO %TempDir%
```