# Get relative path of files in sub-folders from the current directory

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-ise

Is there any straight-forward way (by use of cmdlets or .NET classes) to obtain only the relative path of a file in a sub-folder from a given path?

eg current folder is `C:\MyScript` and there is a sub-folder called `Data` with a file `Test.txt`, so I would like to see `Data\Test.txt` instead of `C:\MyScript\Data\Test.txt`

Comment: I guess this what you want - http://stackoverflow.com/a/499101/763026

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72623579/7571258

Answer (score 137, accepted):

The `Resolve-Path` cmdlet has a `-Relative` parameter that will return a path relative to the current directory:

```
Set-Location C:\MyScript
$relativePath = Get-Item Data\Test.txt | Resolve-Path -Relative
```

Comment: is it possible to define another base directory than the current one ?

Comment: @VinyJones  I haven't found a way but I used Push-Location and Pop-Location as a workaround to temporarily set the current directory to the other base directory in order to get the path relative to that directory.  Kind of clunky but it works for me.

Comment: @VinyJones Yes, if using .net core/.net standard you can use the .net method for this: `[System.IO.Path]::GetRelativePath('c:\temp', 'c:\windows')`.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getrelativepath?view=net-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=netframework-2.0.  For .net framework you'd need to roll your own: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275689/how-to-get-relative-path-from-absolute-path

Comment: @VinyJones They finally added a `RelativeBasePath` option in Powershell 7.4.0 so you don't need to use .NET anymore: `Resolve-Path -Path "C:\Temp" -RelativeBasePath "C:\Windows"`

Answer (score 5):

In case the directory doesn't exist, or the base directory should be different from the current working directory, there's a .NET method `[IO.Path]::GetRelativePath(String from, String to)`.

Comment: Only available in .Net core