# How to find the folders list present between a parent directory and a file created inside many nested subdirectories inside the parent directory

Tags: powershell, microsoft-file-explorer

I am working on to build an automation using Powershell to maintain the proper directory architecture for each individual file inside a server and track them with a record.

We have a parent directory which is *D:\ParentDir* and inside *ParentDir*, we do have multiple nested subdirectories. All here I am trying to get is, if I pick up a file inside these sub directories, what are the sub-directories behind the file from the Parent Directory.

let say

```
$dir = "D:\ParentDir" 
$file = "D:\ParentDir\subdir1\subdir2\subdir3\file1"
```

Here I want to write a PowerShell script to get the folder list between $dir and file1 like

`$dir + n + file1` --> trying to get the folders list 'n'

In the above example, n is \subdir1\subdir2\subdir3

Is there any way to get that information ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get relative path of files in sub-folders from the current directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972589/get-relative-path-of-files-in-sub-folders-from-the-current-directory)

Comment: Thank you for the article but this did not help to fix the issue. The given article only provides the information if we know the sub-directory path. The agenda of my script is find the sub-directories between the parent directory and the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Set-Location $dir
$file |Split-Path |Resolve-Path -Relative
```

Comment: Thank you very much @iRon, this resolved my issue.