# What is the correct way of doing: $attachment = $logdir +'\'+ $logFileName in PowerShell?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to normalize a path in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495618/how-to-normalize-a-path-in-powershell)

I want to get rid of +'\'+ in this file name construction :

```
$attachment = $logdir +'\'+ $logFileName
```

in PowerShell script.

What is the correct way of combining directory name and file name in PS?

Comment: I don't know PS, but pure C# has `Path.Combine`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$attachment =  [IO.Path]::Combine($logdir, $logFileName)
```

Answer (score 6):

try:

```
$attachment = join-path -path $logdir -Childpath $logfilename
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of options and @Christian's way is the formal one. Here's another option that uses variable expansion:

```
$attachment = "$logdir\$logFileName"
```

Comment: Note that this isn't exactly the same as Join-Path or Path.Combine as those functions will handle trailing \s in $logdir. For example if $logdir was "MyFolder\" and $logFileName was "Log.txt" then the path methods would give "MyFolder\Log.txt" whereas yours would give "MyFolder\\Log.txt".

Comment: I'm aware of this and if the script author also aware of the values in those variables then this is a valid option. I do prefer Join-Path though.