# How to test for an invalid path in powershell?

Tags: powershell, path

I have a script that tries to run some executable using a relative path.
So I use `test-path` to verify that the executable is where it is supposed to be.
If not I try another location.

```
if(test-path "$current../../../myexe.exe"){
   # found it!
}
```

But in this case, if the $current is `C:/folder/` then `test-path "C:/folder/../../../myexe.exe"` fails with

> The path ... referred to an item that was outside the base 'C:'

Is there a clean and sure way to test for a path, so that it returns true or false, and won't throw me some unexpected error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work using .NET `File.Exists`, but you have to set the `Environment.CurrentDirectory` first if you want relative path to be resolved correctly.

**EDIT**: not changing CurrentDirectory after Shay Levy pointed out that it can be dangerous for other background processes (see http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2006/06/26/current-working-directory-with-powershell-and-net-calls/ )

<s>[Environment]::CurrentDirectory = $pwd</s>

```
[System.IO.File].Exists("$pwd\$invalidRelativePath")
False
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Test-Path ([io.path]::Combine($current,(Resolve-Path ../../../myexe.exe)))
```

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/499101/9833) for more info:

Comment: I just got it to work, I used [IO.File]::Exists() I think that Resolve-Path would throw the same kind of exception

Comment: I wouldn't change the process working directory, http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2006/06/26/current-working-directory-with-powershell-and-net-calls/

Comment: Interesting, then I should maybe use [IO.Path]::GetFullPath("$pwd\..\..\myexe.exe") to avoid the exception of resolve-path, and then File.Exists to avoir the exception of test-path

Comment: You can use Test-Path instead of the .net class.

Comment: ah that's right, because in this case, GetFullPath takes care of the problematic exception.

Answer (score 2):

Test-path is fundamentally broken.

Even **SilentlyContinue** is broken:

```
Test-Path $MyPath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

This will still blow up if $MyPath is $null, empty, or doesn't exist as a variable.

It even returns $true if $MyPath is only a space. Where the heck is that " " folder!

Below is a workaround that work for the following situations:

```
$MyPath = "C:\windows"  #Test-Path return $True as it should
$MyPath = " "       #Test-Path returns $true, Should return $False
$MyPath = ""        #Test-Path Blows up, Should return $False
$MyPath = $null      #Test-Path Blows up, Should return $False
Remove-Variable -Name MyPath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue  #Test-Path Blows up, Should return $False
```

The solution lies in forcing it to return $False when Test-Path wants to blow up.

```
if ( $(Try { Test-Path $MyPath.trim() } Catch { $false }) ) {  #Returns $false if $null, "" or " "
    write-host "path is GOOD"
} Else {
    write-host "path is BAD"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Resolve-Path or Join-Path