# Need an illegal character '.' in my Azure Function name

Tags: azure-functions

The service I am interacting with makes a call looking for this:

```py
@app.get("/config.yaml")
async def config_manifest():
.
.
.
```

Their sample python works.

I want to spin up an Azure Function and ***not*** use python.

I might not be reading the python code correctly for the endpoint name.

If I am, how can I create that endpoint in an Az Fn, '.' is an illegal character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes **dot . is not supported character in Azure Function Name**, But **you can make use of URL routing** to and route to your required URL:-

***As an alternative to python, You can make use of below Javascript [Nodejs] function code with URL routing:-***

**Code:-**

**index.json:-**

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const yaml = require('js-yaml');

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
  if (req.method === 'GET' && req.url === '/config.yaml') {
    try {
      const configFile = fs.readFileSync('./config.yaml', 'utf8');
      const config = yaml.safeLoad(configFile);
      context.res = {
        status: 200,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'text/yaml'
        },
        body: config
      };
    } catch (error) {
      context.res = {
        status: 500,
        body: error.message
      };
    }
  } else {
    context.res = {
      status: 404,
      body: 'Not found'
    };
  }
};
```

**function.json:-**

```json
{

"bindings": [

{

"authLevel": "anonymous",

"type": "httpTrigger",

"direction": "in",

"name": "req",

"methods": [

"get"

],

"route": "config.yaml"

},

{

"type": "http",

"direction": "out",

"name": "res"

}

]

}
```

**package.json:-**

```json
{

"name": "nodefunc",

"version": "1.0.0",

"description": "",

"scripts": {

"start": "func start",

"test": "echo \"No tests yet...\""

},

"dependencies": {

"express": "^4.18.2",

"js-yaml": "^4.1.0"

}

}
```

**Output:-**

*Got the required url in the HTTP Trigger like below:-*

[image]

***In python you can make use of @app.route decorator in python for url routing like below:-***

**init.py:-**

```py
import logging
import azure.functions as func
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/config.yaml')
def config_manifest():
    # your function logic here
    return 'Config Manifest'

# add more routes here as needed

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "Hello, Azure Functions with Flask!"

@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return "This is a sample Flask app running on Azure Functions."

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    # call the Flask app with the request and return the response
    return func.WsgiMiddleware(app).handle(req)
```

**Output:-**

[image]

You can make use of route decorators for other frameworks too.

**For c#**

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

public static class MyFunctions
{
    [FunctionName("ConfigManifest")]
    [Route("config.yaml")]
    public static IActionResult Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "config.yaml")] HttpRequest req)
    {
        return new OkObjectResult("Config Manifest");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! If I was using PowerShell. What would it look like?

Comment: @DougFinke you can use Get-AbsolutePath https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495618/how-to-normalize-a-path-in-powershell and Resolve-Path refer here -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/resolve-path?view=powershell-7.3

Comment: It would be similar to this - function Invoke-FlaskApp([System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage] $req, [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ExecutionContext] $context) {
    $uri = $req.RequestUri
    $method = $req.Method.Method

    ($uri.AbsolutePath -eq "/config.yaml" -and $method -eq "GET") 
        # execute config_manifest() function for "/config.yaml" route
        $responseContent = "Config Manifest"

    ($uri.AbsolutePath -eq "/" -and $method -eq "GET") {
        # execute home() function for "/" route
        $responseContent = "Hi from flask"